# Smart/Fillable PDF adding more attributes

Tags: pdf, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I am creating a Smart/Fillable PDF using Acrobat Pro DC.

---

I created a word file with 250+ fields(in a tabular manner), exported to PDF and then in "Prepare form" options I added checkboxes, dropdowns and a couple of buttons and the form is ready. Now I want to add 50+ more fields into that PDF but if i follow the same procedure export to PDF and then "Prepare form" then i shall loose all the old validations and scripts I have written initially.

---

To overcome this scenario I tried a couple of things that didn't work for me:

1. Go to "Edit PDF" option and try editing PDF but that did not work as that option helps editing text and images but I have fields in a tabular format so in case if I want to add a table with N x N fields not possible
2. Tried to copy all elements including textbox,checkbox,dropdowns buttons etc but cannot copy all at once, tried then in a small group like 15-15 and that worked but still I had to reposition so not a feasible way
3. Tried to export the elements including textbox,checkbox,dropdowns buttons etc but Acrobat Pro DC doesn't help
4. Many other manipulative things but didn't help.

---

Please help me to overcome this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can not see why copying of more than 15 fields or so should fail; could it be that Acrobat is short on memory? If so, see if quitting other applications improves the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the background of the form, you would first open the old version, and then replace the pages with the ones from the new version. This does not affect any form fields, so, only some repositioning may be necessary.

Then you go to the form edit mode (or use the Select Object Tool (single key accelerator R)) and you can select the fields you want to copy and either drag-copy if you are on the same page, copy/paste them, or duplicate them on other pages (via Context menu of the selected field in edit mode).

Another potentially important hint: deactivate Save as… optimizes for fast web view when working with forms.

Comment: I want to add a couple of more things possibly on all the pages, not feasible

Comment: @RushabhShah: can you explain?

Comment: sure, i have everything in a tabulated format. There are 7-8 tables on each page. Incase if i want to insert a table in a pdf i cant do that so i have to go back to add in word and then add the table (table has more details of user like personal info) and export to pdf then give validations and scripts

Comment: Is this a one-time job, or is the creation of such forms somewhat recurring? In the second case, I might have something, but that would require some in-depth discussion; if you are interested, feel free to contact me in private for further discussion and maybe a quote.